# Как узнать что игра запущена и в нее данный момент именно играют?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим есть какая нибудь игра (например, Need For Speed).

Каким способом можно узнать что в нее именно играют (не просто запущена или стоит на паузе)?

В голову приходит только смотреть на количество используемой оперативной память или видеопамяти. Если больше какого-то значения (узнать опытным путем), тогда играют, иначе если меньше то - стоит на паузе либо вовсе игра не запущена.

Может есть какие то другие методы? Нужно просто в файл записывать сколько времени игрок непосредственно ИГРАЛ в какую либо игру.

Comment: Самое сложное в этой истории - раздать своё приложение всем людям на планете. Но даже если допустить, что это решаемо, то телеметрия системы без согласия пользователя - преследуется по закону. А в некоторых странах уголовно наказуемо, если вы не являетесь резидентом этой страны, по статье "шпионаж". Ну а если действовать полностью скрытно, то это называется вирус.

Comment: Я не думаю, что хорошо будет записывать  в файл время игры, ведь это очень скажется на производительности. Реализовать это можно просто проверяя, на какие клавиши пользователь жмет, просто юзая кейлоггер. Но однако, это тоже на производительность плохо скажется. Но это уже как-то правдоподобней.

Comment: aepot - Причем тут пользователи?? - я пользователь-я игрок!

Comment: Ma3rX - идею понял, да , производительность пострадает конечно. Но тоже как вариант. Может еще есть варианты у кого нть?

Comment: Как объяснили, так я и написал. 1) запущено ли приложение Process.GetProcessByName или на переднем плане ли окно Win API GetForegroundWindow. 2) если да, то логировать клавиатуру - Keyboard Hook.

Comment: Да никак производительность не пострадает от кейлогера. Переключатели раскладки тому доказательство. А так можно смотреть запущенные процессы и какое окно на переднем плане (хотя игра может и на переднем плане стоять на паузе, а свернутое активно жрать ресурсы). А не только какие кнопки не какие жмет, а еще и длительность удержания..

Comment: Для каждой игры нужен будет свой подход, универсальной формулы нет, у каждой игры нужно будет смотреть на свои "псевдодатчики", для одиночных оффлайн игр - можно будет лезть напрямую в память и смотреть определённые значения, а в сетевых играх можно схватить за это банан, но можно смотреть косвенно нагрузку на трафик/работу потоков.